# Why Jest's toThrow won't work when create an instance of a ES6 class directly in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-class

```
class TestObject {
  constructor(value) {
    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
      throw new Error('Expect a value!');
    }
  }
}

describe('test the constructor', () => {
  test('it works', () => {
    expect(() => {
      new TestObject();
    }).toThrow();
  });

  test('not work', () => {
    expect(new TestObject()).toThrow();
  });
});
```

2 Test cases here, one works and the other not.

The failing message for the `not work` one is as the following:

> ● test the constructor › not work
>
> Expect a value!
>
> ```
>  at new TestObject (tests/client/utils/aaa.test.js:4:11)
>  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/client/utils/aaa.test.js:17:12)
>      at Promise (<anonymous>)
>      at <anonymous>
>  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
> ```

Why do I need to wrap that call in a function call, we don't need to wrap when the function just return a plain value, or even a promise, we can use `async/await` to check that in `expect()` rather than create a function inside `expect()`.

What happened here?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here

```
expect(new TestObject()).toThrow();
```

`new TestObject()` is evaluated first, then `expect(...)`, then `...toThrow()`, in accordance with [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). When `new TestObject()` throws, anything else doesn't matter.

This is why `toThrow` expects a function that is supposed to throw:

```
expect(() => {
  new TestObject();
}).toThrow();
```

This way it can be wrapped with `try..catch` internally when being called.

It works similarly in Jasmine `toThrow` and Chai `to.throw` assertions as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing an async function use

```
expect(async () => {await function()}).rejects.toThrow()
```

You can see more details - https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#resolves-rejects