# Parameterize Jest's expect

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I can't pass a function that throws into `expect()` as due to [operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707558/9971404) that will throw before Jest can try-catch it.

So instead of this:

```
expect(thisThrows())
```

We must do this:

```
expect(() => thisThrows())
```

But say I want to parameterize it:

```
test("foo", () => {
  const sut = (arg) => { if (!arg) throw new Error(); };
  expect(sut(undefined)).toThrow();
  expect(sut(null)).toThrow();
  expect(sut(0)).toThrow();
  expect(sut("")).toThrow();
  expect(sut(10)).not.toThrow();
});
```

This still has the original problem.

How can I do something like this neatly, so I can keep my tests DRY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `sut()` throws an error, it cannot be called directly as `expect(sut(undefined)` because the error is thrown immediately and it cannot be asserted.

It should be treated the same way as with `expect(() => thisThrows())`:

```
expect(() => sut(undefined)).toThrow();
```