# How to ensure a react-testing-library test waits for a completed promise chain?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

In my login form, a successful login initiates a promise chain that ends with the user being redirected to the home screen. In the test below, I hope to ensure my login works by capturing that final step.

I have log statements within the code that tell me every step in the promise chain is executed as I expect, but the assertion still fails. It's clear from my logging that the test completes before the promise chain executes.

I think this might be complicated by the behavior of Formik, which I'm using in my actual form. I have not been able to successfully query and wait for the spinner that is displayed while the login is under way.

I'm at a loss as to how to get this test to wait until the navigation occurs. What promise resolution could be triggering `waitFor` to complete?

```
import { act, render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react"
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event"

import React from "react"

import { AuthProvider } from "context/auth-context"
import { rest } from "msw"
import { setupServer } from "msw/node"
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"
import { LoginScreen } from "screens/login"
import { handlers } from "test/auth-handlers"
import { buildLoginForm } from "test/generate/auth"
import { deferred } from "test/test-utils"

const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <Router>
    <AuthProvider>{children}</AuthProvider>
  </Router>
)
const serverURL = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL
const server = setupServer(...handlers)

const mockNav = jest.fn()
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
  useNavigate: () => mockNav,
}))

beforeAll(() => {
  server.listen()
})
afterAll(() => server.close())
afterEach(() => {
  server.resetHandlers()
  jest.clearAllMocks()
})

test("successful login", async () => {
  const { promise, resolve } = deferred()

  render(
    <Wrapper>
      <LoginScreen />
    </Wrapper>,
  )

  expect(screen.getByLabelText(/loading/i)).toBeInTheDocument()

  await act(() => {
    resolve()
    return promise
  })

  const { email, password } = buildLoginForm()

  userEvent.type(screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: /email/i }), email)
  userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/password/i), password)
  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"))

  await waitFor(expect(mockNav).toHaveBeenCalledWith("home"))
})
```

The login form:

```
function LoginForm({ onSubmit }) {
  const { isError, isLoading, error, run } = useAsync()

  function handleSubmit(values) {
    // any 400 or 500 is displayed to the user
    run(onSubmit(values)).catch(() => {})
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email address").required("A valid email is required"),
        password: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
      })}
      onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
    >
      <Form>
        <FormGroup name="email" type="text" label="Email" />
        <FormGroup name="password" type="password" label="Password" />
        <IconSubmitButton loading={isLoading} color="green">
          <MdArrowForward style={{ marginTop: ".6rem" }} />
        </IconSubmitButton>
        {isError ? <ErrorDisplay error={error} /> : null}
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`waitFor` is unaware of promises or other implementation details, it works by polling provided assertion in specified intervals until an assertion passes or a timeout occurs.

`waitFor` works similarly to [`toThrow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707558/3731501) in terms of error handling. There's no way how it could catch errors and evaluate an assertion multiple times when it's specified as an argument, `expect` is called once, throws an error and fails the test:

```
  await waitFor(expect(mockNav).toHaveBeenCalledWith("home"))
```

The only way `waitFor` can work is when it's provided with a function that can be wrapped with `try..catch` internally and executed multiple times. A correct way to do this is:

```
  await waitFor(() => expect(mockNav).toHaveBeenCalledWith("home"))
```

Comment: Thank you, @Estus! Really obvious now that you pointed it out.

Comment: You probably do not need the `await` before the `waitFor`, this is redundant as `waitFor` carries out the callback as many times as it needs to until timeout or success. Maybe if you had other assertions following which rely on a certain state being reached first, but here you only have one.

Comment: @TomDickman await is needed, it doesn't affect how waitFor works but affects its effect on a test. Basically a test doesn't wait for a condition that waitFor is supposed to satisfy, this defies the purpose.